# Change Sharepoint Online subsite URL

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I have a subsite in Sharepoint Online with a web address of

https://mydomain/sites/sitecollectionName/subsite

Is it possible to change the url to

https://mydomain/sites/subsite

If I understand correctly it is possible in sharepoint 2013 using powershell 
[Get-SPWeb and setting ServerRelativeUrl](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2013/11/06/how-to-change-the-structure-of-sharepoint-site-in-a-site-collection/)
but SPO does not appear to have similar powershell commandlets

Comment: I guess you are trying change subsite to site collection, but i guess its not possible just by changing the server relative url

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint Online, we can't change the site collection URL, we can change the sub site URL using PowerShell with CSOM. The following PowerShell script for your reference:

```
#Configure Site URL and User
$SiteURL = "https://mydomain/sites/sitecollectionName/subsite"
$User = "username@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = "Password"
$newUrl= "/sites/sitecollectionName/mysubsite"


Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User,$SecurePassword)

$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$context.Credentials = $creds
$web = $context.Web
$context.Load($web)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$web.ServerRelativeUrl = $newUrl
$web.update()
$context.ExecuteQuery()
```

[How to change the Subsite URL property using PowerShell in SharePoint Online](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/How-to-change-the-Subsite-6b8b7b04)

Comment: Here in question looks like he is trying to convert subsite to a site another collection. Does this server-relative URL change work for this?
I guess its only for changing subsite URL respective to its site collection URL not to another site collection.

Comment: The suggested script works only if I keep the sitecollection path as part of the new url
https://mydomain/sites/sitecollectionName/newsubsite

I want to change url to
https://mydomain/sites/subsite 
effectively removing the reference to SiteCollection in the path
I get an exception "Invalid URL" when I run the script
So looks like not possible

Comment: Yes, the script work for change the sub site url, not change site collection url.